# An active access token must be used to query information about the current user on different url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was developing facebook app which was hosted on test machine. Everything was ok and today I wanted to push it on production. I have changed page url on facebook developers and from that moment when I try to use this app there is an error:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user
```

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like:

1) You don't have an access token or your access token does not match the current logged in user.

OR, more likely based on your description:

2) You have an expired or non-working access token (perhaps left over from the last time you used the app?). You could try clearing that out and reauthenticating.