# Posting with PHP to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An active access token must be used to query information about the current user on different url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180023/an-active-access-token-must-be-used-to-query-information-about-the-current-user)

I have been trying to figure out how to post something to Facebook from a php form, but I keep on getting an error, I don't understand:

> 2500: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

I created an app, got the appID and appSecret, and use the following code:

```
        $config = array(
                    'appId' => $this->config->Facebook->Api,
                    'secret' => $this->config->Facebook->Secret,
                    'cookie' => true
                    );

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);

        echo "Facebook: " . print_r($facebook, true) . "<br>";

        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

        $facebook->setAccessToken($token);

        echo "Facebook: " . print_r($facebook, true) . "<br>";

        $attachment = array(
            'message' => 'this is my message',
            'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
            'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
            'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
            'description' => 'this is a description',
            'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif'
        );

        $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
        echo "Result: " . print_r($result, true) . "<br>";
```

I also tried without the setAccessToken, setting the token as a parameter in the message:

```
        $config = array(
                    'appId' => $this->config->Facebook->Api,
                    'secret' => $this->config->Facebook->Secret,
                    'cookie' => true
                    );

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);

        echo "Facebook: " . print_r($facebook, true) . "<br>";

        $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

        echo "Token: " . print_r($token, true) . "<br>";

        $attachment = array(
            'message' => 'this is my message',
            'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
            'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
            'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
            'description' => 'this is a description',
            'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif',
            'access_token' => $token
        );

        $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
        echo "Result: " . print_r($result, true) . "<br>";
```

I tested both ways because I went through several stackoverflow posts and other resources from other sites, but none of these work, as I keep on getting the following error:

> 2500: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: Its been a little while since I worked with the Facebook API. If I recall, you have two different access tokens. One application level token, which is needed for some non-user specific operations. And a user token, in which the user has to authenticate your application to allow your application to access user info or post on your behalf (depending on what permissions you ask for)

Comment: Do you have a login step before you try to post something? By login i mean making sure user has given you the permissions to access info and post on his wall?

Comment: Well I don't understand why this has been closed if no answer exists in stackoverflow, and the post mentioned does not help, but nevermind... @Darvex: all the code I have is the one I posted above. I simply copied the appID and appSecret from the app I created after creating my facebook account. I want to post to my account, as myself. I am not trying to post anything on behalf of other users, I just want a way to post something or updating my status through PHP, without having to go to facebook.

Comment: Ultimately, what I need to achieve is to be able to post to a page of a company. I read that I needed to create another profile in order to be able to create an app. Now I wanted to try out posting to that profile using the app, and then figure out how to post to that company page...But I am either going blind or I can't seem to find anywhere with a clear documentation on how to do this...